# Как изменить код, чтобы писать меньше информации Swift

Tags: swift

Делаю приложение под ios. Сам еще новичок. Есть 2 view для получения видео из ютуба. Написал вот такой код:

```
import UIKit

class TestTwoVideoViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      getVideo(videoCode: "_DtXTqEOe4g")
      getVideo1(videoCode: "ZylYsZ4qKyU")
       
    }
  
    @IBOutlet weak var playerView1: UIWebView!


    @IBOutlet weak var playerView2: UIWebView!
    
    func getVideo (videoCode:String) {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoCode)")
        playerView1.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    
}

    func getVideo1 (videoCode:String) {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoCode)")
        playerView2.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    
}
    
}
```

Как его изменить, если нужно будет добавить еще view, чтобы не создать каждый раз новую функцию?

Comment: Оставьте только одну функции и один аутлет. И вызывайте только эту одну функцию с разными videoCode и на одном и том же playerView.

Comment: Тогда у меня будет только одно видео показываться на экране, а мне надо несколько в разных местах экрана

Comment: Тогда вам не нужна функция, просто вызовите столько раз, сколько нужно: playerView1.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!)), playerView2.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!)), playerView3.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!)) и т.д., вместо url подставьте нужную строку.

Comment: Спасибо. Подправил. Все получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал вот так. Вроде меньше кода стало.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class TestTwoVideoViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      
      playerView1.load(URLRequest(url:URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/_DtXTqEOe4g")!))
      
      playerView2.load(URLRequest(url:URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZylYsZ4qKyU")!))
       
    }
  

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView1: WKWebView!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var playerView2: WKWebView!
    
}
```